# PHP setCookie and getCookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am working on this PHP application, and I set a cookie and then redirect to another pager after after when I set my cookie.

When I got to my new page and try to access my cookie, it telling me that

```
if ($num > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

            setcookie("userid", $row[0]);
            setcookie("username", $username);

            header("Location: ../direction/Exist.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            setcookie("username", $username);
            setcookie("password", $pass);
            header("Location: ../direction/NewMember.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

    mysqli_close(checkConnection());
}
```

And I my NewMember.php page, I am accessing the cookie with this code.

```
$username = $_COOKIE["username"];
$password = $_COOKIE["password"];
```

> Undefined index: username in line 5

This is the line I am trying to access my cookie on.

Below is the code of how I set my cookie.

Any help please.

Comment: Don't set your users passwords in cookies. You'll also need to specify the cookie expiry date & potentially the path too - [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie). You'd be better using sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suggests that the cookie is created and read in different URL paths. You'll need to override the path (4th argument) in which the cookie will be available on.

```
setcookie("username", $username, 0, "/");
```

---

From the [setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) path argument documentation:

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.